# Why do we need a variational formulation if a classical solution always exists?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

I read that for an open, bounded domain $\Omega \in \mathbb R^n$ the Poisson equation 
$$-\Delta u = f$$
with given boundary data in fact does always exist and is unique for Dirichlet boundary data or unique up to a constant for Neumann boundary data.

Why do we even bother a variational formulation to obtain a weak solution?

Comment: The variational (or weak) formulation is typically the one used to establish existence of a solution for this kind of elliptic BVP. Are you proposing that a different approach towards existence is better?

Comment: Would you prefer to find Greens function for every "nice enough" domain $\Omega$ to proof existence?   
Another problem is that differential operators often do not have nice enough properties, like continuity and working with those kind of operators can be really tricky.

Comment: @F.Conrad Do you have some literature reference where I can read about finding Greens function to show existence?

Comment: The concept of Greens function for a domain is discussed in the second chapter of "Partial Differential Equations" by Lawrence C. Evas. He preceeds to construct this "fundamental solution" for some regions like e.g. the unit ball. The book is quite popular, so you probably find it quite easily on- and offline.